# Truncated tar.gz archieve after download by a self-coded download manager using socket

Tags: c, sockets, http, tcp

i try to code my own download manager using c and sockets, now somethings strange happens and I really cannot explain why.

So what I do is: I create sockets, connect to server, create and send a GET Request.
Everythings is fine so far. The download starts, when its finished, I search the byte(char) array for '\n\r\n' to get to the end of the header(one further for start of the message body).
From there on I write msg_size-(header_end+1) bytes to a file. the resulting file has exactly the same byte size as if I download the file regulary. But when I try to extract it, it errors on a "unexpected end of file", while the other version extracts just fine.

Does anybody maybe have a explanation for that, also i can provide code, Im just not sure 
where the problem can be, so i was trying first to verbalize the problem.
I tried allready the "wb" and "w" flag.

also the server does not specify chunked transfare or compressed encoding.
It is http/1.1 though.

Thanks!

edit:
so this is the server Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 16:33:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Sun, 17 Jan 2010 18:17:39 GMT
ETag: "3ba006-29b376-47d60407b56c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2732918
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

edit2;
and this is how i recieve and write the file:

```
    memset(file,0,file_size);
    arg[1]=recv(socketfd,file,file_size,0);
    int mstart=0;
    while(file[mstart]!='\n' ||file[mstart+1]!='\r'|| file[mstart+2]!='\n'){
       mstart++;
    }
    mstart+=3;
    fsize=file_size;
    int fsize=file_size-mstart;       //file_size from Response Header
    fwrite(&(file[mstart]),1,fsize,fd);
    fclose(fd)
```

ok, that makes a lot of sense, so i tried this now:
(edit) mistake in there but this also doesnt work:

```
  fd=fopen(file_name,"wb");  
  memset(file,0,file_size);
  recv(socketfd,file,3,0);
  while(1==1){
    if(file[0]=='\n' ||file[1]=='\r'|| file[2]=='\n'){
      recv(socketfd,file,3,0);
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  arg[1]=recv(socketfd,file,file_size,MSG_WAITALL);
  fwrite(file,1,file_size,fd);
  fclose(fd);
```

but its still now wokring

Finally! this works know, thanks alot to you!

```
  fd=fopen(file_name,"w");  
  memset(file,0,file_size);
  recv(socketfd,file,3,0);
  while(file[0]!='\n' ||file[1]!='\r'|| file[2]!='\n'){
      recv(socketfd,file,3,0);
  }
  arg[1]=recv(socketfd,file,file_size,MSG_WAITALL);
  fwrite(file,1,file_size,fd);
  fclose(fd);
```

Comment: when receiving are you sure you are limiting START and EOF to the file only ??

Comment: What do `Content-Type` and/or `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers say?

Comment: Use a checksum program like md5sum to verify that the two files are identical.  You can also use something like `diff`  (windiff if you are on windows) to see the difference between the .tar.gz you download and the original .tar.gz that will tell you where the issue is arising from;  It would be useful to see the read/write loop you are using to dump the file; also as an experiment you can write the ENTIRE reply to a file, and (1st test) manually and then (2nd test) automatically as a separate the file content that way you can debug the right thing.

Comment: Upon a second look, do you get partial extraction?

Comment: @mf_ i down't understand your question.

Comment: @user315052 i do not use range request and the server does not use chunked rtansfare.

Comment: are you consuming or discarding the server header properly ? + are you receiving till the server closes the connection  ?

Comment: @Ahmed Masud i will check your first suggestion, i allready did dump the whole file at once to debug, but what do you mean by manually and automatically separatint the file(how to do that manually)?

Comment: @AhmedMasud, yes i get partial extraction

Comment: ok diff sais that the files differ same size though, do you know a command for diff I can use to see where they differ exactly. i use linux

Comment: @mrblack okay you have a file dump right? what I meant by manually was to use an existing tool; If are you on a Un*x environment or windows? because if you are on unix/linux you can use something like dd to remove the header as in `dd if=dump of=foo.tar.gz   ibs=1 skip=<header-bytes>` this way you can figure out whether it's happening in the readsocket()/write() loop or whether it's post close() that your error shows up

Comment: @mf_ i wait for the server to finsih the transfare, in precise, i wait till recv() doesnt recieve anything anymore, i do close the connection then later

Comment: @mrblack okay simpler and simpler let's see your code I think you are making a logic mistake in your write-out and I bet you it's either the last block or the last byte that's screwy

Comment: @ahmed-masud,

i bet on the first byte, and even didnt see the code

Comment: @mf_ mmm would .gz survive a first byte shift? think not.  I said it's the last byte/chunk because he is getting a partial output. although +1 for the blind bet hehe :)

Comment: @mrblack okay serious ugliness in your code are you sure you're pasting it correctly? can you paste the entire function in pastebin and post a link?

Comment: How did you determine `file_size`? Is it from the content length header?

Comment: @mrblack not only that there is a redeclaration of fsize for some reason as in fsize = file_size and then int fsize = file_size - mcount;  If you are picking up file_size from content-length then you should NOT subtract mcount from it ... because that content-length is EXACTLY your .tar.gz file size

Comment: @AhmedMasud when i use your shell command i get: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: @AhmedMasud are you sure about the content lenght? because when i do that, i never get the corresponding ammount of recieved bytes from recv() even with the WAITALL FLAG, if i do it this way, i get the exact ammount by recv() as shown in the response header

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sJubKXuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file reading logic doesn't quite work. You first need to read some fixed amount, and parse that fixed amount to find the end of the headers. Then you parse the headers to find the content length. Then any data you have already read past the end of headers gets written out as the first part of your file. The rest of the file is the content length minus what you have written. It is that many more bytes you have to read from the socket and write to the file.

Your problem is that you have not properly utilized the content length header (which you had extracted from a previous HEAD request). It indicates the size of the transfer following the headers, not the length of the entire response.

The reason the file appears to be the correct size is that you are writing out the correct number of bytes, but you are reading past the end of the bytes you read from the socket (since you have adjusted `mstart` forward past the end of headers).